# Create Auto Repeated Records by Time

Tags: vba, ms-access

I just new in access, and I have to face up the DB everyday. In this case, I create a form to record scedule of planned maintenance (next I call it "PM") which has variaties divided of time by week, month and year. Every PM that has been created, it has an unique number of PM. The number is as follows : 162/PNT/PM/06/2020. The number was containing with : "unique number"/"PM's area"/"type of maintenance"/"month"/"year".
Then, is there a way to create records repeatly based on time or previous PM schedule with the same content?

For an example :
I create a monthly PM schedule which the number is 001/PNT/PM/01/2020 on 20-Jan-2020. When I press the save button (or copy schedule button), the record will copying (creating) to 20-Feb-2020 with changed PM's number to 002/PNT/PM/02/2020 automatically.

Thanks for anyone who wants to help me.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Use VBA. Generating unique sequential identifier is a common topic. But creating and saving this identifier is not really necessary. These elements should each be saved in individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

June is right. Use a table like this:

```
ID        - Long
PNT       - Short Text
PM        - Short Text
StartDate - DateTime
```

and a query to assemble the code:

```sql
SELECT 
    Maintenance.ID, 
    Maintenance.PNT, 
    Maintenance.PM, 
    Maintenance.StartDate, 
    Format([ID],"000") & "/" & [PNT] & "/" & [PM] & "/" & Format([StartDate],"mm\/ddyy") AS Code
FROM 
    Maintenance;
```

Output:

[image]

Now, to create the next record, use:

```
NextID = ID + 1
NextDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)
```

[image]